# ngRepeat doesn't update when the $scope updates

Tags: angularjs

Update 2: I found the problem. It was with my data. After I received the data, I I was trying to access it incorrectly. I should've used data.data instead of data.

Update:

I discovered the following code seems to be preventing me from running anything after it:

```
$scope.items.push({
                                id : data.item.id,
                                item : data.item.item,
                                qty : data.item.qty,
                                type : data.item.type,
                                type_name : data.item.type.type_name,
                                done : data.item.done
                            });
```

When I click the add button, a new item gets created in the database. However ngRepeat doesn't update until I do a hard refresh. How can I get the page to update as soon as I press the Add button?

// index.html

```
<body ng-controller="ShoppingListController">
    <button type="button" class="small button" ng-disabled="!goodToGo()" ng-click="insert()">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"> Add</i>
    </button>

<form id="addForm" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">
                        <span class="spanLabel" ng-show="!minimumCharactersMet()">You need at least {{ howManyMoreCharactersNeeded() }} characters more.</span>
                        <span class="spanLabel" ng-show="isNumberOfCharactersWithinRange()">Remaining characters: {{ howManyCharactersRemaining() }}</span>
                        <span class="spanLabel warning" ng-show="anyCharactersOver()">{{ howManyCharactersOver() }} characters too many</span>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-8 columns">
                        <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="item" 
                        placeholder="Item" 
                        ng-model="item"
                        ng-trim="false">
                    </div>


                    <div class="large-2 columns">
                        <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="qty" 
                        placeholder="Qty/Weight"
                        ng-model="qty"
                        ng-trim="false">
                    </div>


                    <div class="large-2 columns">
                        <select 
                        name="type"
                        ng-model="type">
                            <option value="{{ type.id }}" ng-repeat="type in types">{{ type.name }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">
                        <div class="show-for-medium-up">
                            <div class="flr">
                                <button type="button" class="small button primary" ng-click="print()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-print"> Print List</i>
                                </button>

                                <button type="button" class="small button alert" ng-click="remove()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-time"> Clear Completed</i>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <button type="button" class="small button" ng-disabled="!goodToGo()" ng-click="insert()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"> Add</i>
                            </button>

                            <button type="button" class="small button secondary" ng-click="clear()">
                                    <i class="fa fa-ban"> Clear Entry</i>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="show-for-small-only">
                            <ul class="button-group even-4">
                                <li>
                                    <button type="submit" class="small button" ng-disabled="!goodToGo()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button type="submit" class="small button secondary" ng-click="clear()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button type="button" class="small button primary" ng-click="print()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button type="button" class="small button alert" ng-click="remove()">
                                        <i class="fa fa-time"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

    <form id="items">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id" ng-class="{ 'done' : item.done == 1 }">
            <div class="small-8 columns itemName">
                <label for="item-{{ item.id }}">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="item-{{ item.id }}" id="item-{{ item.id }}" ng-model="item.done" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-change="update(item)">
                    {{ item.item }}
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="small-2 columns itemQty">
                {{ item.qty }}
            </div>

            <div class="small-2 columns itemType">
                {{ item.type_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

// myApp.js

```
app.controller('ShoppingListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'helperFactory', function($scope, $http, $log, helperFactory) {

    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.item = '';
        $scope.qty = '';
    };

    $scope.insert = function() {
        if ($scope.goodToGo()) {
            var thisData = 'item=' + $scope.item; 
            thisData += '&qty=' + $scope.qty; 
            thisData += '&type=' + $scope.type;
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : urlInsert,
                data : {
                    'item' : $scope.item,
                    'qty' : $scope.qty,
                    'type' : $scope.type
                }
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                if (_recordAddedSuccessfully(data)) {
                    $scope.items.push({
                        id : data.item.id,
                        item : data.item.item,
                        qty : data.item.qty,
                        type : data.item.type,
                        type_name : data.item.type.type_name,
                        done : data.item.done
                    });

                    $scope.clear();
                }
            }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong with inserting record')
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Why do you call  $scope.clear();

Comment: @MarcusH I edited my post to show more of my code. I use $scope.clear() because there's a 2nd form with a bunch of text inputs, and the $scope.clear() allows the text fields to be cleared after adding an item.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you don't have to call $scope.apply explicitly as its the part of Angular digest cycle. But, in your case i see `$scope.clear()` which is not making any sense here. You can remove that line and use $scope.apply() instead and see if your changed model is reflecting in view.

Here is the [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) that talks about angular digest cycle you may want to refer.

Try below if it works:

```
app.controller('ShoppingListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'helperFactory', function($scope, $http, $log, helperFactory) {

    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.item = '';
        $scope.qty = '';
    };

    $scope.insert = function() {
        if ($scope.goodToGo()) {
            var thisData = 'item=' + $scope.item; 
            thisData += '&qty=' + $scope.qty; 
            thisData += '&type=' + $scope.type;
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : urlInsert,
                data : {
                    'item' : $scope.item,
                    'qty' : $scope.qty,
                    'type' : $scope.type
                }
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                if (_recordAddedSuccessfully(data)) {
                    $scope.items.push({
                        id : data.data.item.id,
                        item : data.data.item.item,
                        qty : data.data.item.qty,
                        type : data.data.item.type,
                        type_name : data.data.item.type.type_name,
                        done : data.data.item.done
                    });

                    $scope.apply();
                    $scope.item='';
                    $scope.qty='';
                    $scope.type='';
                }
            }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong with inserting record')
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I edited my post to show more of my code. There was actually a bunch of text fields that were submitted. I use to clear() to make the fields empty after adding the item.

Comment: You might wanna try clearing them after $scope.apply(). Try that if it works.

Comment: I discovered there's a problem with my $scope.items.push({...}). It's preventing any code after it from running for some reason.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was with my data. After I received the data, I I was trying to access it incorrectly. I should've used data.data instead of data.